# Let $\small\mathbf H=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&a\end{pmatrix}$ Show that $ e^{\mathbf Ht}=e^{at}\small\begin{pmatrix}1&bt\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $\mathbf H=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&a\end{pmatrix}$ Show that
>   $e^{\mathbf Ht}=e^{at}\begin{pmatrix}1&bt\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$

I have $$\begin{aligned} &Ht=\begin{pmatrix}at&bt\\0&at\end{pmatrix} \\ & \iff e^{Ht}=e^{\begin{pmatrix}at&bt\\0&at\end{pmatrix}}=e^{at \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&bt\\0&0\end{pmatrix}} \\ &\iff e^{Ht}=e^{at\cdot I}e^{\begin{pmatrix}0&bt\\0&0\end{pmatrix}}\end{aligned}$$

but how do I continue?

Comment: First of all - comment - your last equality is correct - but you have to justify the argument - it's true because the two matrices being exponentiated commute (multiplicatively).  To answer your question: to get to the next step: use the power series expansion of $e^x$ on the two factors. (In fact, I think you need the power series expansion of exponentiation to show $e^{x+y} =e^xe^y$ for commuting $x$ and $y$ too.)

Comment: @peterag Thank you Peter. Could you maybe explain what it means that "exponentiated (matrices) commute multiplicatively". Should I use a taylor expansion $f(A)=\sum \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}A^n$ or the matrix exponential function $exp{A}=sum \frac{1}{n!}A^n$?

Comment: The T.S of $f(x) = e^x$ is $ \sum x^n/n!$ so you can use the latter. Exponentiation for matrices - what does that actually mean? - one way to define it as the power series. That being the case, why would $e^{x+y}= e^x e^y$ hold? One can prove it as formal power series in commuting $x$ and $y$: one way is to prove it is with calculus - this gives a formal identity in power series - we can rearrange commuting $x$ and $y$ to go from one power series to the other...

Comment: But Petite Etincelle's specific argument is good! note the use of the commutativity of matrices...

Comment: For completeness... Clarification on my "prove it with calculus" above - I meant viewing $x\mapsto e^x$ as a function of a real variable $x$...

Comment: Sorry for my late reply but my Internet just decided to stop working so i had to get to the library. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, $e^{\mathbf Ht}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{t^n\mathbf H^n}{n!}$

$\mathbf H^n = \left(\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}0&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\right)^n = \begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix}^n + n\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix}^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}0&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a^n&na^{n-1}b\\0&a^n\end{pmatrix}$
since $\begin{pmatrix}0&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}^k = 0, k \geq 2$ and $\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ commute

So we have $e^{\mathbf Ht} =\mathbf I+  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!} \begin{pmatrix}a^n&na^{n-1}b\\0&a^n\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(at)^n}{n!}&bt\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(at)^n}{n!}\\0&\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(at)^n}{n!}\end{pmatrix} = e^{at}\begin{pmatrix}1&bt\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Thank you! Really good answer.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again but I don't understand how the second entry $$na^{n-1}b$$

becomes $$bt\sum_{=0}^{\infty} \frac{(at)^n}{n!}$$

Where did the $a^{n-1}$ part of the term go?

Comment: @bluemoon $\frac{na^{n-1}}{n!} = \frac{a^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$. Sorry I have to catch a flight. I will be back tomorrow if it's still not clear